# Outlook email - Html table cell's background color does not work? :-/

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

What html script should I use to make the table's cell background color works in MS-Outlook 2007 and 2010??

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="background-color:#ffff00">Background color</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link for supported HTML and CSS tags in Outlook 2007:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx

MS also offers an HTML/CSS Validation Tool for Outlook 2007 at the URL above. That may at least provide you with a method of testing.

I have found that "Less Is More", when it comes to HTML emails - simple layout, simple techniques. Since each email client is going to vary, "dumbing" it down is the only way to guarantee the broadest reach.

Comment: The page you link to does say that `background-color` is supported, so that's not the answer. +1 though for your recommendation to tone down the special effects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I post my answer in case someone else finds this post.

I found this tool to be a good solution (should work in all email clients):
http://backgrounds.cm/